# Most efficient way to send mass emails in multi-tenant site?

Tags: sendmail, sendgrid

I have a multi-tenant site. Some of my clients send out 1 email here and there, others might send out 1,000 at one time.

I'm using [SendGrid.com](http://sendgrid.com) as my mail server and [SwiftMailer.org](http://swiftmailer.org/) for my PHP code.

The issue is each email takes a second or so to send. I guess it needs to connect to SendGrid.com to authenticate etc. So if you send 1,000 emails, it would in essence take about 1,000 seconds it times out.

What I think is the best way is to store the emails in the database and then a cron job sends them out.

Would that be te most effective way? And should I only send out a certain amount of emails at a time? So for example 100 per cron job?

While I'm on the subject of cron jobs, can cron jobs over lap? So if I made it run the cron job every minute, and the page took 2 minutes to send all the emails, would the cron job run again after a minute or would it wait 2 minutes until the last cron job has processed?

Thanks for your help!

Ben

Answer (score 1):

You have an IO bound task (network / network service IO in this case).

IO bound tasks are ideally suited for multi-threading.

Kick off multiple threads in your sending application to handle multiple email send requests in parallel.

If you wish to periodically check whether emails are ready to be sent, cron is a fine choice.  However, you may wish to consider a daemon (a.k.a. service) that constantly runs (and perhaps sleeps intermittently) as an alternative.